# Is it illegal to create a website that allows a user to upload a file and make it accessable and downloadable for others?

Tags: copyright, internet, online-piracy, online

I am working on a website in which a user can sign in and upload a file and other users can search for it by name and download it. Those files will be catagorized as audio, video, apps(linux, windows, mac), documents etc. So, I was wondering if it is legal or illegal. I'll also add a "report" option with each file by which visitors can report a pirated content.

Comment: This is the very definition of every single website in existence.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of existing legal sites that do this, for free or for pay. The main concern for a website operator pertains to the [DMCA "safe harbor" provisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Copyright_Infringement_Liability_Limitation_Act), which protect against vicarious liability for infringement. A "report piracy" option is not sufficient; see [this answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/24057/how-can-i-legally-protect-my-website-from-users-who-upload-copyrighted-material/24060#24060) to a related question.